# Change 2 layout in the same portlet

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

I have a portlet. I get a search engine layout X and when I look I continue to see this layout X in which I had to hide columns with Javascript to change the design, which takes 2 seconds to disappear this layout and was the main layout appears. Once the JS hidden charge me the other columns.

What I like:

As you might do. I have a portlet with a search engine with a layout X and find me display a layout Y.

Could pick up some parameter that when you click find me change the layout Y?

Thank you!!!

Comment: It might be a language issue, but I have no clue what you're asking for. Could you illustrate with (fake) screenshots or another description? What do you have already, what do you intend to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to change you portlet/page layout on change of screen orientation?Please provide some snapshots or requirement details along with the issue.